# null pointer error- Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting  null pointer exception and I'm really confused.
can anyone help me please? if you need more information,please let me know.thanks in advance for your help.here's the activity file:

```
public class AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private  MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event
     * plays a song and changes button to pause image
     * pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event
     * Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event
     * Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Next button click event
     * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
     * */
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check if next song is there or not
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Back button click event
     * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
     * */
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Repeat button
     * Enables repeat flag to true
     * */
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }   
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Shuffle button
     * Enables shuffle flag to true
     * */
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }   
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Play list click event
     * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
     * */
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed
 * if repeat is ON play same song again
 * if shuffle is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if(isRepeat){
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }
```

}

and here's the LOGCAT:

```
 06-19 02:22:17.080: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
06-19 02:22:17.080: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a12ba8)
06-19 02:22:17.330: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 3143K/3292K, paused 204ms, total 216ms
06-19 02:22:17.360: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(837): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Process: com.androidhive.musicplayer, PID: 837
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.musicplayer/com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.androidhive.musicplayer.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:25)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.onCreate(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:77)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-19 02:22:17.370: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  ... 11 more
```

songmanager file:

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a `NullPointerException` in `SongsManager.java`, line 25. Debug it and check.

Comment: Its throws  an error at line No. 25, what is code at line 25 in your class ?

Comment: please post code  of SongsManager classs  also. and check getPlayList returns values.

Comment: make sure you have proper and accessible MEDIA_PATH(/sdcard/). if you are testing it on an emulator, check if that emulator has SD Card property added to it. and also, check if you have added neccessary permissions in the android manifest to access these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. the line:

> if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0)

is throwing an error.It could be solved this way:

```
public class SongsManager {
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager() {

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` throws at this line: `songsList.add(song);`(line 25)

You seems forgot to create a new instance for this `songsList`